# AWS data set naming

Tags: bash, python, amazon-web-services

I am trying to pre process data and since i am inexperienced i am hitting dead ends

I have a bucket named, region figured out, but now it is giving me the error:

```
enter codcovid-19-testing-data-master % ./init.sh -s covid-data-7438djk2 -d "COVID19_DMPROJ" -r us-east-1
```

```
updating: .DS_Store (deflated 93%)
updating: __pycache__/ (stored 0%)
updating: __pycache__/source_data.cpython-310.pyc (deflated 38%)
uploading pre-preprocessing.zip to s3
upload: pre-processing/pre-processing-code/pre-processing-code.zip to s3://covid-data-7438djk2/COVID19_DATAPROJ/automation/pre-processing-code.zip
creating dataset on ADX

An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateDataSet operation: The following parameter(s) are not valid: "Name" is not allowed to be empty.e here
```

here is the code for the script in question

https://oldwestburyedu-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/jhuerta3_oldwestbury_edu/EcdJC10phPVGiwiBJDOT9akB7kiBfgnaRgf3TQqtA8u72Q?e=H0zHXJ

Comment: It’s not clear how this is Apple centric and not something related to AWS.  Perhaps this is a better fit for [SO]?  Can you clarify why you believe this is related to Apple/macOS?

Comment: oh you are right

Comment: sorry i thought i was on stack overflow

Comment: No worries.  Don’t delete.  I flagged and the mods will migrate it.  No need to rewrite

Comment: You have linked to a very big script. It is unlikely that somebody will work through that entire script trying to figure out what is happening. The script is also referring to CloudFormation stacks that are outside of the provided script. Where did the script come from? Was there any documentation? It seems remarkably similar to [federal-reserve-consumer-credit/init.sh at master · rearc-data/federal-reserve-consumer-credit · GitHub](https://github.com/rearc-data/federal-reserve-consumer-credit/blob/master/init.sh)

Comment: Please show the specific commands that failed instead of expecting people to understand your whole script